# native-base tabs doesn't call lifecycle method componentWillUnmount

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm using `native-base`, `redux` and `react-native`, It seems that switching between tabs doesn't call the method `componentWillUnmount`, I want to do some actions when the tab is switched and the component is removed:

**Main.js**

```
export class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Container style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Tabs initialPage={0}  >
        <Tab heading="Tab1">
            <Tab1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab2">
            <Tab2 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

**Tab1.js**

```
export class Tab1 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

  componentWillMount(){   
    //called 
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    //not called when switching tabs
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Content>
          <Text>Tab1</Text>
        </Content>
    </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

How to call actions when the tab is switched and the component is removed?

Comment: Do you need to unmount the latest tab component? It will reduce the performance of you code and will cause rendering the tab in every call.

Comment: I want to do some actions when the tab is switched

Comment: what is the process here ? what are the life-cycle methods called when switching between tabs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onChangeTab` prop in the `<Tabs>` tag to listen the tab change event like the example below:

```
<Tabs 
  renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab />} 
  onChangeTab={(obj) => {
    // obj = {
    //   i: currentPage,
    //   ref: this._children()[currentPage],
    //   from: prevPage,
    // }
    //do something with obj
  }}>
    <Tab heading="Tab1">
      <Tab1 />
    </Tab>
    <Tab heading="Tab2">
      <Tab2 />
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: can we know which tab is switched to ?

Comment: Yes you can access this kind of info. I update my answer and also you can see the source code of `Tabs` component here: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Tabs/index.js

Comment: Happy to help you.